# Error loading Crystal Report in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm having difficulty in making the correct code related to crystal report viewing.

Locally (on my development machine), when I try to load the report, it is working fine, but when I upload the file to our live/web server, when I clicked the print button, the error below shows up.

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12:     
> Line 13:     
> Line 14:         <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
> Line 15:     
> Line 16:

I've been working on this since a very long time but I can't find the answer.

Crystal Report version that I am using: Version=13.0.2000.0

Visual Studio version : 2013 (x86)

Need for your advise and suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you install the correct SAP Crystal Report Runtime Assembly?  Keep in mind, you may need to install both the x86 and x64 versions if your project in Visual Studio has a target CPU of "Any CPU".

Comment: Yes, I installed both 32bit and 64bit version of crystal report runtime. I tried every solutions and suggestions i've read from different web sources like 1. enabling 32bit in iis application pool, 2. adding the log4net.dll, 3. recreate the report from scratch, 4. reinstalling the crystal report, etc. I don't know why locally the report is working fine but on live server, error keeps showing. Do you have any idea how can i check if i uploaded all the needed and necessary dll's from my local to live server? or what files do i need to include for this to work? Thank you.